# silentoldconfig fails to build when adding new symbol to AOSP config

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, android-source, ninja

I am trying to add a linux kernel driver to the android source.

I add it in the config file to be built (kernel/msm-4.9/arch/arm64/config/sdm845_defconfig).

```
CONFIG_LEDS_QPNP_WLED=y
# CONFIG_LEDS_QPNP_HAPTICS is not set
CONFIG_HAPTICS_MISC=y
```

The makefile and Kconfig files in kernel/msm-4.9/drivers/misc/ are also updated to include the driver.

Makefile:

```
haptics-misc-objs := haptics-misc.o hatpics-misc-tables.o
obj-$(CONFIG_HAPTICS_MISC)   += haptics-misc.o
```

Kconfig:

```
config HAPTICS_MISC
        tristate "Haptics driver"
        depends on I2C && SYSFS && NEW_LEDS
        help
          Boosted Haptics Driver
```

I attempt to build the kernel with the following steps:

```
 $ source build/envsetup.sh
 $ lunch 41
    ============================================
    PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
    PLATFORM_VERSION=8.1.0
    TARGET_PRODUCT=sdm845
    TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
    TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
    TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION=OPM1
    TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
    TARGET_ARCH=arm64
    TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
    TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=kryo300
    TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
    TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
    TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a9
    HOST_ARCH=x86_64
    HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
    HOST_OS=linux
    HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.15.0-24-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
    HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
    HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
    HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
    HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
    BUILD_ID=OPM1.171019.026
    OUT_DIR=out
    AUX_OS_VARIANT_LIST=

   $ make -j12
```

The build fails with the following error:

```
Haptics driver (HAPTICS_MISC) [N/m/y/?] (NEW) aborted!

Console input/output is redirected. Run 'make oldconfig' to update configuration.

/media/ftreven/quarter-b/Open-Q_845_Android-O_v1.0/Source_Package/SDA845_Open-Q_845_Android-O_v1.0/kernel/msm-4.9/scripts/kconfig/Makefile:37: recipe for target 'silentoldconfig' failed
make[3]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
/media/ftreven/quarter-b/Open-Q_845_Android-O_v1.0/Source_Package/SDA845_Open-Q_845_Android-O_v1.0/kernel/msm-4.9/Makefile:550: recipe for target 'silentoldconfig' failed
make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/config/kernel.release'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/ftreven/quarter-b/Open-Q_845_Android-O_v1.0/Source_Package/SDA845_Open-Q_845_Android-O_v1.0/out/target/product/sdm845/obj/kernel/msm-4.9'
Makefile:150: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

It seems from the error message that the command fails solely because the symbol is new. It recommends to make oldconfig but this also fails:

```
$ make oldconfig
ninja: error: unknown target 'oldconfig', did you mean 'fmconfig'?
13:08:18 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (38 seconds) ####
```

I am uncertain what "fmconfig" is but I attempt to build it as suggested and it succeeds. However, attempting to build the whole kernel fails for the same reason as above. Any idea what could be causing this? It was built successfully prior to adding the new symbol.

Comment: `make oldconfig` => `ninja: error: ...` - What? How is ninja related with building the Linux kernel? Are you sure that in this case you run `make` from the proper directory?

Comment: Yes, I have built successfully multiple times prior to adding the driver.

Comment: I am not about the building the kernel, I am about configuring it using `make oldconfig`. It is rather strange that output of `make` includes "ninja" - ninja is another build system, and, as far as I know, it is not used by the kernel build process.

Comment: It is not only building the kernel, but the android space as well.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now, I switched into the kernel directory inside the android directory and built it from there successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that after Linux kernel version 4.9 was released, the android framework stopped allowing built-in drivers. To get around this I had to instead build the drivers as Dynamically Loadable Kernel Modules. To do this I created a directory under vendor/ called dlkm/ where I place all source code and configs/Makefile.

After this is done I can build the source successfully.

```
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch 41
$ make -j12


#### build completed successfully (03:38 (mm:ss)) ###
```

There can be no reference to the driver in the actual kernel part of the android framework or the build will fail. The exception to this is for device trees (.dtsi, .dts files) which will still be built within the kernel.